# To save files to IIS virtual directory from WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2008, iis

I am using WCF service in my application.All services are hosted as window service. I have one virtual directory in IIS to save user file (may be PDF or TXT). I want to create a particular folder for each user and keep their information file in that folder. How can I create a folder and upload file to IIS via WCF?

For example: the virtual directory path is `http://10.10.10.1/TempUserFolder/`

I want to create a folder for `UserID = 1` like `http://10.10.10.1/TempFolder/UserID1/`.
And then save his information file to that folder, `http://10.10.10.1/TempFolder/UserID1/Info.pdf`.

I got a error message `URI formats are not supported` when I use `System.IO`. Please guide me in right way. I really appreciate your help. I am using VS200

Comment: Your post is somewhat contradictory.  You state that your services are hosted as Windows services but you're referring to IIS virtual directories.  If your services are indeed hosted as Windows services then why are you trying to use IIS virtual directories?  What does the code look like that is causing these errors?

Comment: @Chong if u get the solution of this will u please share the code or the link where i can get the answer act i didn't understand the way Brijesh tell.
so please help if u can i am stuck in the same situation and using webHttpBinding in my case..
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your windows service is on same IIS host server, you can very well use absolute path, say if http://10.10.10.1/TempFolder/ maps to c:/TempFolder/, in WCF windowsservice when recieving file create new folder in c:/TempFolder/ and store file there, and if its on different machine you can create network share and then create folder and copy files to that location.

You can find many article on web to demonstrate how to upload file via wcf

http://stefanoricciardi.com/2009/08/28/file-transfer-with-wcp/

Answer (score 0):

To get the physical directory name, use

```
Server.MapPath('TempFolder/UserID1');
```

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments, the above solution will only work when using asp.net compatibility in an IIS-hosted solution.

If you don't want to hard-code the directory, for example if this is deployed to different servers, you can get the directory of the WCF assembly, then figure out the relative relation of the desired directories from there.

For example, assuming that the DLL is in the bin directory and the temp directory is 1 level up, the following code should work:

```
string sDirectory = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location;
sDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(sDirectory, "..\TempFolder\UserID1");
```

Comment: hi Competent_tech,
thanks for your answer.Can you give me some example?I don't know how I use it in wcf application.I already tried HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("TempFolder") but it always return null.I think it can only use in web based application.

Comment: That will only work if hosting in IIS and ASP.Net compatability mode is enabled

Comment: @chris.house.00: excellent point. I am too used to a combined WCF/Web app solution. I have updated the answer with a different solution. Thanks for the sharp eye.

Answer (score 0):

This will give a virtual directory of current application.With this you can append your created folder name

```
    public string GetIISPath()
    {
        string urlscheme = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme;
        string host = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
        int port = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port;         

        //Ignore Http Port
        if (port != 80)
            host = host + ":" + port;
        string vPath = urlscheme + "://" + host + "/";
        return vPath;
    }
```